# how we can get custom product grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, xml, product-grid, custom-extension

I have tried to create a product grid custom extension
[image]

but product grid filter is not working and I am not able to save data

this is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit;
class Tabs extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('slide_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Artists Album'));
    }
    
     protected function _prepareLayout()
        {
            
            $this->addTab('main_section',
                [
                    'label' => __('Album Information'),
                    'title' => __('Album Information'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\Main')->toHtml(),
                    'active' => false
                ]
            );
            $this->addTab('img_section',
                [
                    'label' => __('Images'),
                    'title' => __('Images'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\Images')->toHtml(),
                    'active' => false
                ]
            );
            
            // $this->addTab('video_section',
                // [
                    // 'label' => __('Video'),
                    // 'title' => __('Video'),
                    // 'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     // 'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\Video')->toHtml(),
                    // 'active' => false
                // ]
            // );
            
            $this->addTab('video_section',
                [
                    'label' => __('Video'),
                    'title' => __('Video'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                        'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\Video'
                    )->toHtml(),
                    'active' => false
                ]
            );

            
            $this->addTab('tab_section',
                [
                    'label' => __('tab_section'),
                    'title' => __('tab_section'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\CustomTab')->toHtml(),
                    'active' => false
                ]
            );
            
            $this->addTab('social_media',
                [
                    'label' => __('social_media'),
                    'title' => __('social_media'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\MyConnection')->toHtml(),
                    'active' => false
                ]
            );
            
            $this->addTab('my_product',
                [
                    'label' => __('my_product'),
                    'title' => __('my_product'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\MyProduct')->toHtml(),
                    'active' => false
                ]
            );
            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }
    
}
```

'Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab\MyProduct

to get all product in grid

```
<?php


namespace Magebees\Artists\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class MyProduct extends Extended
{

     /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory
     */
    protected $_linkFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
     */
    protected $_setsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_status;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_visibility;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $linkFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $linkFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
        ) {
        $this->_linkFactory = $linkFactory;
        $this->_setsFactory = $setsFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_type = $type;
        $this->_status = $status;
        $this->_visibility = $visibility;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Set grid params
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('related_product_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        
        
    }

    /**
     * Add filter
     *
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _filterCollection($collection, $column)
        { die('dsas..');
            if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                return $this;
            }  

            if ($value['from']) {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('position', ['gteq' => $value['from']]);
            }

            if ($value['to']) {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('position', ['lteq' => $value['to']]);
            }

            return $this;
        }
    
    // Inside your grid block class
protected function filterProductPosition($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if ($value['from']) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('position', ['gteq' => $value['from']]);
    }

    if ($value['to']) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('position', ['lteq' => $value['to']]);
    }

    return $this;
}

    
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->getProductsRelated();
        if (!is_array($products)) {
            $products = array_keys($this->getSelectedRelatedProducts());
        }
        return $products;
    }
    /**
     * Retirve currently edited product model
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getBanner()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_banner');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection
     *
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_linkFactory->create()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

   

    /**
     * Add columns to grid
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        
            $this->addColumn(
                'in_products',
                [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_products',
                'values' => '',//$this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
                ]
                );
        

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
            'header' => __('ID'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
            'header' => __('Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-name',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-name'
            ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'type',
            [
            'header' => __('Type'),
            'index' => 'type_id',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->_type->getOptionArray(),
            'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-type'
            ]
            );

        $sets = $this->_setsFactory->create()->setEntityTypeFilter(
            $this->_productFactory->create()->getResource()->getTypeId()
            )->load()->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn(
            'set_name',
            [
            'header' => __('Attribute Set'),
            'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $sets,
            'header_css_class' => 'col-attr-name',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-attr-name'
            ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'status',
            [
            'header' => __('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray(),
            'header_css_class' => 'col-status',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-status'
            ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'visibility',
            [
            'header' => __('Visibility'),
            'index' => 'visibility',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->_visibility->getOptionArray(),
            'header_css_class' => 'col-visibility',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-visibility'
            ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
            'header' => __('SKU'),
            'index' => 'sku',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-sku'
            ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
            'header' => __('Price'),
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
            'index' => 'price',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-price',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-price'
            ]
            );
  $this->addColumn(
    'position',
    [
        'header' => __('Position'),
        'name' => 'position',
        'type' => 'number',
        'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
        'index' => 'position',
        'header_css_class' => 'col-position',
        'column_css_class' => 'col-position',
        'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, 'filterProductPosition'],
    ]
);

        

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    
     public function getSelectedRelatedProducts()
    {
        $banner = $this->getBanner();
        $products = [];
        if(!empty($banner->getRelatedProducts())){
            foreach ($banner->getRelatedProducts() as $product) {
                $products[$product['entity_id']] = ['position' => $product['position']];
            }
        }
        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * Rerieve grid URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
   public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'artists/slide/relatedProductsGrid', // Replace with the correct URL path
            ['_current' => true] // Add any required parameters
        );
    }
}
```

anyone please help me.

How will this filter work? and how I can save the data. I have created **product_data_base_file**.